# Send emails using SendGrid and Amazon work email

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, email, sendgrid

I want to send emails using SendGrid and Amazon work email in Android app.
How can I do that in an Android app using Java?

Comment: They have an API.  It may or may not work on Android (its a jar file, which can work if it doesn't use parts of the Java standard library Android doesn't support).  I'd start by trying that

Answer (score 0):

SendGrid does have a [Java library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java) and an [API which you can use to send email](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send). However, these both require an API secret which would not be safe to store inside of a client application like an Android app. But technically, you could do it. Instead though, I'd recommend hosting that code in a Java web application, and creating a secure API to which your Android app can communicate.

To send email from an email address that you're also using for Amazon work email, you'll need to either [verify a single sender](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification) (good for testing), or [setup domain authentication](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication). However, this is sending email using SendGrid, not using Amazon work email, so you won't see these emails from SendGrid in your outbox if that's what you want. Replies to these emails will go to the usual email inboxes in your Amazon work email.